# Как отлаживать ошибки вида PermGen OutOfMemory в Джаве?

Tags: java, jvm, visualvm, heapdump

Вопрос можно разбить на следующие:

1. Содержит ли обычный `HeapDump`, который выкидывается при `OutOfMemoryError`, информацию о `PermGen`?
2. Что нужно, чтобы подключиться к Джава-коду такими средствами, как `jstatd` или `jconsole`. Нужно ли его запускать с определенными параметрами? Что нужно, чтобы можно было подключиться к удаленному коду из VisualVM?
3. Есть ли какие-то средства для анализа того, что выдает `jmap -permgen`? Там совсем непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

1. нет не содержит
2. не знаю
3. без понятия

Мысли:

- имхо такие трудные ошибки без логгера будет сложно ловить, пологгируйте ваш код
- если не лечится увеличение пространства для *permgen*, значит где-то есть утечка. Скорее всего проблема в кастомном загрузчике класса, посмотрите код связанный с рефлексией классов.